# Algorithm for shifting data

Tags: algorithm

I was bored and sketched out this idea in pseudocode( I will try to turn it into C++ later) for taking a set of numeric data and manipulating it. I ran through it manually and it seems to put the data in a range `[0, something]`

```
count =
data[count] = { d_0, d_1, … , d_(count -1) }
sigma = $Σ_{a∈ℕ} data_a$
avg = sum / count

newData[count] = {}

for x in data
  append (x · avg)/count to newData
```

What I am curious about, is if this "doodle" has any potential uses, or if it can be extended somehow?

Comment: Also: I am very sorry that the MathJax will not render,my device dislikes markdown...

Answer (score 1):

Your computer will get bored, too, dividing (`over`?) by *count* over and again. Use
*avg_count* = *sum* / *count* / *count* - or
*scale* = *something* / *sum*

Comment: So... useless, I think is what you are saying?

Comment: I guess I fail to see *algorithm*, and I'm not sure ***I*** like to see *pseudocode* here. From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code`.